# How can I give the selected row ID from a table to my model?

Tags: php

Well, I don't actually know where the problem is but my modal doesn't get the ID of my selected row.

My modal needs to get the description of the selected row. So if you select row 2 in my table you need to get the description of ID 2 in my database.

```
<tr data-toggle='modal' value=".$row["ID"]." data-target='#myModal' id=".$row["ID"].">
                                     <td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td>
                                     <td>" . $row["Name"]. " </td>
                                     <td>" . $row["Category"]. " </td>
                                     <td>" . $row["Skill"]. " </td>
                                     <td>" . $row["CareerCompetence"]. " </td>
                                     <td>" . $row["DateAdded"]. " </td>
                                     <td>" . $row["EmailUploader"]. " </td> 
                                     <td> ";
                                     ?>
                           <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                             <div class="modal-dialog">

                               <!-- Modal content-->
                               <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                   <?php
                                   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM class where ID='".$row['ID']."'";
                                   $result2 = $con->query($sql2);
                                   while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                                     ?>
                                   <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $row2["Name"]; ?></h4>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                   <p><?php echo $row2['Descriptie'];?></p>
                                   <p><?php echo $row2['FileName'];?></p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                 </div>
                               </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome Jeroen, would yo mind formatting your code for easing anyone else looking at it

Comment: my problem is already solved by a friend of my. But thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: You can self-answer it by posting a new answer and explain in it what you did to solve it. Its a polite gesture to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is now solved by a friend of mine by adding a one click to my tr. If u click on a row in the table now you get a pop up with the description of that row. Code of the table below:

```
// Head of the table
<thead>
    <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>category</th>
   <th>Skills</th>
   <th>competenties</th>
   <th>date added</th>
   <th>Email uploader</th>
   <th>Visable</th>
   <th>Approve</th>
   <th>Disapprove</th>
</tr>
</thead>



// Data of the table 

$data = "<p>".$row['Descriptie']."</p>"; //data is the Description of the row you send it to your modal by using \"OpenModalWith('$data')"
 <tr onclick=\"OpenModalWith('$data', '".$row["Name"]."');\" data-toggle='modal' value=".$row["ID"]." data-target='#myModal' id=".$row["ID"].">
 <td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td>
                                      <td>" . $row["Name"]. " </td>
                                      <td>" . $row["Category"]. " </td>
                                      <td>" . $Skill. " </td>
                                      <td>" . $Competences. " </td>
                                      <td>" . $row["DateAdded"]. " </td>
                                      <td>" . $row["EmailUploader"]. " </td> 
                                      <td> ";
```

This is the modal ( row['description'] is the description of the row ):

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">

                                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p><?php echo $row2['Descriptie'];?></p>

                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
```

In my javascript code, he says get the elementbyID so, for example, myModal (myModal is my modal ID )

```
function OpenModalWith(content, title){
          modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
          modaltitle = modal.getElementsByClassName("modal-title")[0];
          modalbody = modal.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
          modalbody.innerHTML = content;
          modaltitle.innerHTML = title;

      }
```